# C++ template explicit instantiation declarations: best practices

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, extern, explicit-instantiation

My question is how we should use **template explicit instantiation declarations** in a right way?

Suppose we have some template class `template<class T> Foo`.

Here is my mind how to deal with this feature:

We put template declaration in `Foo.h` file, implementation in `Foo.inl` file, include this `Foo.inl` in the end of the `Foo.h` file, put `extern template class Foo<int>;` after `#include "Foo.inl"`. Also we should use **explicit template instantiation definition** in, for example, `Foo.cpp` file (of course we should also inlcude `Foo.h` in this cpp file).

If we do all this stuff we got an error: we cannot use **explicit template instantiation definition** just after **explicit template instantiation declaration**. Ok, lets put template declaration and `#include "Foo.inl"` in separate file `Foo.hpp` and include it in `Foo.cpp`. Eventually we got this:

Foo.hpp

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  ...
};

#include "Foo.inl"
```

Foo.inl

```
template<class T>
Foo<T>::Foo() {}
```

Foo.h

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
extern template class Foo<int>;
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.hpp"
template class Foo<int>;
```

And use this template ike this:

test1.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
void bar()
{
  Foo f;
}
```

***Too many Foo's do not you think?*** How do you deal with this?

Sorry for my english.

### UPDATE:

The question is not about **explicit template instantiation definitions** or methods of configuring of the template code inself it is about **explicit template instantiation declaration** usage and about the "files hell" which is prodused if we are trying to use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template multiple definition issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810526/template-multiple-definition-issue)

Comment: What's the point of .h and .hpp, just ditch one? You can't get rid of the .cpp file if you want to instantiate it. You could get rid of the .inl file if you have proper documentation tools, thought it might not be a good idea.

Comment: @csiz, in this case I've create two `*.h` and `*.hpp` files cuz if I left only `*.hpp` file and put `extern template class Foo<int>` inside it I could not include this `*.hpp` file in `*.cpp` file. You cannot use explicit instantiation definition and explicit instantiate declaration in one file (`*.cpp` in this case)

Comment: Hmm, seems to just work for me http://cpp.sh/6jbe

Comment: @csiz, maybe it is VS2013 quirks. Here is error screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8WIZg5ldEQaSkxTU0k5VVFVQU0

Comment: I copied your code into http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ and it also works. Sorry don't know how to help you here.